# More views of a form in c#

Tags: c#, ios, view

Let's say I have two "views". Each view has it's own button, which makes other view to appear. All should be managed in one window. So how do I achieve this? Im looking for something like viewController in iOS...

I tried to use one filled, docked panel - but than all classes are active, so it doesn't seem like a good solution. I also tried user classes ([like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mECkft9LG4k)), it works, but it's complicated and I have big deal sending data between these classes.

Comment: Is this asp.net or windows application or something else? Are you using any framework or not?

Comment: Check if this helps - [CodeProject - Creating a Multi-Page Windows Forms Control with Design Time Support](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21489/Creating-a-Multi-Page-Windows-Forms-Control-with-D#)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "views" of a form. The concept of what a UIViewController can do in iOS is different than building a properly functioning form in C#. You need to learn some new skills now and approach this from a different perspective.

The basic principle is to build a form with controls (either manually or through code or both), change the properties of those controls manually or through code and use the methods they support. You can do what you want, but it's going to take learning some new things.

Try checking this out:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360kwx3z(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you should look into User Controls or Composite Controls.